# .click function for selenium works inconsistently - chrome

Tags: selenium

I have this simple code to click the first paper link `Organoid Modeling of the Tumor Immune Microenvironment.` at [this link](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/?term=%2210x+Genomics%22%5BAffiliation%5D).

```
title_wait = WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "docsum-title")))

print('found title '+str(title))
element = WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, str(title)))).click();

print('found link to click')
```

My code will sometimes work, but around 50% of the time it just skips right over the `.click()` and goes to the print below. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Increase the time from 5 to something larger. Webdriver waits increment every 500 ms for 5 seconds may miss the element.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the problem is not with the wait time. U have made a small mistake in this line: `element = WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, str(title)))).click();`

First of all, title is a variable of type `selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement`. When u convert this into a str, u get this: `<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="21a8944e81b4dce8386fdf91067a2ddd", element="17660b77-61f4-4b2d-b5e8-f845ce97ad1e")>`. So this is not the right way to get the text.

The right way is to use `.text`. Replace `str(title)` with `title.text`. Ur code should work. Here is the final code:

```
title = WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "docsum-title")))

print('found title '+ title.text)

element = WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT , title.text))).click();

print('found link to click')
```

As Arundeep pointed out, u can increase the wait time to make ur code better. But this was the main problem in ur code.

Comment: Actually thought he set up the title somewhere else due to  it not bugging out during the print. title_wait -> str(title)

Comment: Can u rephrase ur comment? I am not able to understand what u wanna convey.

Comment: His variable was title_wait instead of title so it wouldn't even work 50% if that was the case.

Comment: That's y I changed ```title_wait``` to ```title``` in my answer.

Comment: If he wants to grab the text from the first docsum and click the first  matching link it works.

Comment: Ok...That was what he wanted right? Would u mind upvoting my answer?

Comment: no, i already got the text for the title. the print statement prints out the correct title text so this is not the issue

Comment: @BrianGuan My code clicks the first link under the search.